# VBA - Import All Rows from Table in SQL to Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

With much of the code coming from this tutorial:

https://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-sql-server-import-export-using-vba.htm

I have successfully managed to import the desired table from my DB to excel onto a new worksheet.

However, I have noticed that there are +- 230 lines missing from the sheet, that are present in the DB table. Looking at the code, I don't see any real reason as to why it would not import the entire table. I am hoping someone here will be able to point out any mistake/error.

**Code:**

*Functions:*

***ImportSQLtoQueryTable***

```vb
Function ImportSQLtoQueryTable(ByVal conString As String, ByVal query As String, ByVal target As Range) As Integer

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = target.Worksheet

    Dim address As String
    address = target.Cells(1, 1).address

    'Procedure recreates ListObject or QueryTable
    'For Excel 2007 or higher
    If Not target.ListObject Is Nothing Then

        target.ListObject.Delete

    'For Excel 2003
    ElseIf Not target.QueryTable Is Nothing Then

        target.QueryTable.ResultRange.Clear
        target.QueryTable.Delete

    End If

    'For 2007 or higher
    If Application.Version >= "12.0" Then

        With ws.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array("OLEDB;" & conString), Destination:=Range(address))

            With .QueryTable

                .CommandType = xlCmdSql
                .CommandText = StringToArray(query)
                .BackgroundQuery = True
                .SavePassword = True
                .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

            End With

        End With

    'For Excel 2003
    Else

        With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=Array(conString), Destination:=Range(address))

            .CommandType = xlCmdSql
            .CommandText = StringToArray(query)
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .SavePassword = True
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

        End With

    End If

    ImportSQLtoQueryTable = 0

End Function
```

***StringToArray***

```vb
Function StringToArray(Str As String) As Variant

    Const StrLen = 127
    Dim NumElems As Integer
    Dim Temp() As String
    Dim i As Integer

    NumElems = (Len(Str) / StrLen) + 1
    ReDim Temp(1 To NumElems) As String

    For i = 1 To NumElems

       Temp(i) = Mid(Str, ((i - 1) * StrLen) + 1, StrLen)

    Next i

    StringToArray = Temp

End Function
```

***GetTestConnectionString***

```vb
Function GetTestConnectionString() As String

    GetTestConnectionString = OleDbConnectionString( _
        "Server Location", _
        "Connection type", _
        "Username", _
        "Password")

End Function
```

***OleDbConnectionString***

```vb
Function OleDbConnectionString(ByVal Server As String, ByVal Database As String, ByVal Username As String, ByVal Password As String) As String

    If Username = "" Then

        MsgBox "User name for DB login is blank. Unable to Proceed"

    Else
        OleDbConnectionString = _
        "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" & _
        "Data Source=" & Server & "; " & _
        "Initial Catalog=" & Database & "; " & _
        "User ID=" & Username & "; " & _
        "Password=" & Password & ";"
    End If

End Function
```

*The main Sub:*

***TestImportUsingQueryTable***

```vb
Sub TestImportUsingQueryTable()

    Dim conString As String, query As String
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim tmpltWkbk As Workbook
    Dim target As Range

    'Set workbook to be used
    Set tmpltWkbk = Workbooks("Template.xlsm")

    'Need to add check if sheet already exists
    'If sheet already exists then just refresh table

    'Add a new sheet called "DB Table"
    Set DestSh = tmpltWkbk.Worksheets.Add
    DestSh.Name = "DB Table"

    With DestSh

        .UsedRange.Clear
        Set target = .Cells(2, 2)

    End With

    'Get connection string
    conString = GetTestConnectionString()

    'Set Query to table
    query = "SELECT * FROM master.dbo.kw_keyword_tbl"

    Select Case ImportSQLtoQueryTable(conString, query, target)

        Case Else

    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: I would start by removing the line "on error resume next", then forget that statement exists. That is basically saying to the code, if you get an error just ignore it and keep going. Maybe you encountered 230 errors, but you would never know. Let errors happen and deal with then gracefully. Errors happen, they provide a lot of useful information. They should not be shoved under the rug and hidden.

Comment: Can you check any special characters in table.

Comment: @SeanLange Thank you for the reply. I am aware that `On Error Resume Next` is a dumb way to deal with errors, however, in this case it just throwing an error on the `If Statements` for the conditions that it was an `Excel 2003` workbook. Other than that, no errors.

Comment: @SaketYadav Thank you for the reply. I'm not too sure I understand the question...

Comment: How would you know if there are no other errors? Most of the code begins with ImportSQLtoQueryTable. Any error from there to the end of the method gets swallowed.

Comment: @SeanLange No, I mean in the context of errors appearing, there are none. With reference to your first comment on removing `On Error Resume` next, there are no errors.

Comment: I agree with the comment related to `On Error Resume Next` , however I also agree that sometime is just much easier to get over an error, than deal with it... in those cases however, if you are confident you can skip that error, you should encapsulate that specific part of the code only with `On Error Resume Next` --- some code --- `On Error GoTo 0`, rather than the whole script.

Comment: How do you know there are no errors? You literally coded this to catch an error and move on silently. Sadly error handling in VBA is really awful. It is so much easier when you capture certain types of errors and handle them differently. If you are certain there are no errors why not remove that line and run your code again? You might just find the issue you are looking for.

Comment: I was able to use successfully your code with no changes (appart from the obvious sql con details)... how many rows you have in your kw_keyword_tbl table ?

Comment: @SeanLange sorry, I think I’m missing something lol.. Are you saying that the line “On Error Resume Next” isn’t the only thing that could be suppressing failures?

Comment: @DarXyde thank you for the replies. At the moment there are just over 450 lines in the DB and only 211 are pulling through to the workbook..

Comment: Try just selecting a couple of columns from the table, maybe the issue is with a particular column's data.

Comment: No that line is suppressing errors. Remove it and the errors will reveal themselves.

Comment: Never use `On Error Resume Next` alone. Always implement a full error handing. Otherwise you are blind for all errors. You might benefit from reading [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling)

Comment: @SeanLange lol that’s what I’m trying to say.. I removed the line after your initial comment and ran the code again and I didn’t get any errors..

Comment: @Pᴇʜ thank you for the reply. Will read up a bit on it. :)

Comment: LOL either I missed that you removed it or you didn't say that. :) Running around in circles. I don't anything glaring that would cause lines not to get brought over.

Comment: It would help to [edit] the question and remove it there so further readers don't run into the same thing (suggesting to remove that line). The code in the question should reflect the code you actually use.

Comment: @SeanLange lol I do apologize. But yeah, like you say, nothing else seems to be the cause if you look at the code as it is and it executed with no errors..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the `TestImportUsingQueryTable` sub on this line:

1. `query = "SELECT * FROM master.dbo.kw_keyword_tbl"`

And in the `GetTestConnectionString` Function on this line:

1. `"Connection type", _`

These were pointing to the MASTER DB and not to specific DB I needed for this scenario and they BOTH had the same data up to line 211.

**Updated Code:**

In the `TestImportUsingQueryTable` sub:

`query = "SELECT * FROM db1.dbo.kw_keyword_tbl"`

in the `GetTestConnectionString` Function:

```
Function GetTestConnectionString() As String

    GetTestConnectionString = OleDbConnectionString( _
        "Server Location", _
        "db1", _
        "Username", _
        "Password")

End Function
```