# VBA - SQL Query DB Table to Excel With Special Characters in Table Name

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I posted a previous question regarding SQL Query to Excel here:

[VBA - Import All Rows from Table in SQL to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55242472/vba-import-all-rows-from-table-in-sql-to-excel)

Which, turned out to be an oversight issue which I have since resolved. Now, however, I face a new issue when trying to import a different table.

When I first got the macro put together, it was for a table named with underscores such as: **my_table_1_query**

Now, I attempted to use the exact same code with the table name such as: **my-table_query_1** and I get an error on this line:

```
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

Error Message:

> Incorrect syntax near '-'

This is in the function ***ImportSQLtoQueryTable***

Here is the code:

*Functions*

**ImportSQLtoQueryTable**

```vb
Function ImportSQLtoQueryTable(ByVal conString As String, ByVal query As String, ByVal target As Range) As Integer

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = target.Worksheet

    Dim address As String
    address = target.Cells(1, 1).address

    'Procedure recreates ListObject or QueryTable
    'For Excel 2007 or higher
    If Not target.ListObject Is Nothing Then

        target.ListObject.Delete

    End If

    'For 2007 or higher
    If Application.Version >= "12.0" Then

        With ws.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array("OLEDB;" & conString), Destination:=Range(address))

            With .QueryTable

                .CommandType = xlCmdSql
                .CommandText = StringToArray(query)
                .BackgroundQuery = True
                .SavePassword = True
                .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
                .ListObject.Name = "DB KW Component Table"

            End With

        End With

    End If

    ImportSQLtoQueryTable = 0

End Function
```

**StringToArray**

```vb
Function StringToArray(Str As String) As Variant

    Const StrLen = 127
    Dim NumElems As Integer
    Dim Temp() As String
    Dim I As Integer

    NumElems = (Len(Str) / StrLen) + 1
    ReDim Temp(1 To NumElems) As String

    For I = 1 To NumElems

       Temp(I) = Mid(Str, ((I - 1) * StrLen) + 1, StrLen)

    Next I

    StringToArray = Temp

End Function
```

**GetTestConnectionString**

```vb
Function GetTestConnectionString() As String

    GetTestConnectionString = OleDbConnectionString( _
        "Server Location", _
        "Connection DB", _
        "Username", _
        "Password")

End Function
```

**OleDbConnectionString**

```vb
Function OleDbConnectionString(ByVal Server As String, ByVal Database As String, ByVal Username As String, ByVal Password As String) As String

    If Username = "" Then

        MsgBox "User name for DB login is blank. Unable to Proceed"

    Else
        OleDbConnectionString = _
        "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" & _
        "Data Source=" & Server & "; " & _
        "Initial Catalog=" & Database & "; " & _
        "User ID=" & Username & "; " & _
        "Password=" & Password & ";"
    End If

End Function
```

*Sub:*

**TestImportUsingQueryTable**

```vb
Sub TestImportUsingQueryTable()

    Dim conString As String, query As String
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim tmpltWkbk As Workbook
    Dim target As Range

    'Set workbook to be used
    Set tmpltWkbk = Workbooks("New DB.xlsm")

    'Need to add check if sheet already exists
    'If sheet already exists then just refresh table

    'Add a new sheet called "DB Table"
    Set DestSh = tmpltWkbk.Worksheets.Add
    DestSh.Name = "DB Table"

    With DestSh

        .UsedRange.Clear
        Set target = .Cells(2, 2)

    End With

    'Get connection string
    conString = GetTestConnectionString()

    'Set Query to table
    query = "SELECT * FROM SAT_Keyword_DB_X7.dbo.kw_link-tbl_keyword_components"

    Select Case ImportSQLtoQueryTable(conString, query, target)

        Case Else

    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Try using `[` round the text so `[tricky_named-table]`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Wow, can't believe it was so easy. Thank you for the reply :)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your object names in square brackets to tell SQL Server that everything within them should be treated as text, so in your case `my-table_query_1` should be passed as `[my-table_query_1]`